Work done by gas and it's limits
So I have read about how when pressurised gas does work, it decreases in temperature (turbo expanders, Claude liquefaction etc.). How exactly does that work? The more work a gas does, the more it loses heat? So if I increase the load on an turbo expander for example, will that result in a greater temperature difference? And if so, surely there must be a limit. Because in a way the walls of the cylinder that holds the gas would also be a “load“ which does not make sense.

Temperature is NOT heat. The thermal part $TS$ of the internal energy $U=TS-pV+\mu N$ at a certain temperature is entropy $S$ times temperature $T$. A body can do work thereby reducing its internal energy, and if the work is done adiabatically and reversibly then the body's entropy $S$ stays constant while its temperature decreases.

A key aspect of expansion work is a retreating boundary; as gas molecules bounce off this boundary, they transfer momentum to it and thus slow down. (Picture throwing a ball against the back wall of a retreating truck; the rebound is reduced.)
With work done by the gas $P\,dV$ (external pressure $P$, infinitesimal volume change $dV$, and ignoring any heat transfer, the change in internal energy $U$ of the gas is $dU=-P\,dV$, and the corresponding temperature change is thus $dT=\frac{dU}{C}=-\frac{P\,dV}{C}$, where $C$ is the constant-volume heat capacity of the gas. (Note that "constant-volume" is just part of the name of the relevant material property; it doesn't constrain the process in this context.) For a nearly constant heat capacity and external pressure, we can integrate this to obtain $\Delta T=-\frac{P\Delta V}{C}$.
For a fixed container volume, the gas does exert a pressure on the container walls, but with no expansion, the momentum change upon collision is zero and—again in the absence of heat transfer—the gas maintains a constant internal energy and temperature.
Does this get at what you're asking about?

Yes pretty much, but how would you maximise the temperature difference? Telling by that equation, I have to maximise the change in volume when the gas does work? How exactly would this equation apply for a turbine? Im thinking of refrigeration usage.

Start with the condensed phase.

I mean by letting the gas do work on a turbine. Surely evaporation helps, but how would you use your equation for expansion turbines? I guess that system is described by aerodynamics. But how?

Perhaps you're looking for something closer to this discussion.
